No subject alternative DNS name matching updates.jenkins.io found while installing jenkins plugins
When I am trying to install plugins from updates.jenkins.io from my Jenkins instance, it is failing with the error:
java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching updates.jenkins.io found

When I try to check the SSL details, I am getting like:
echo | openssl s_client -connect updates.jenkins.io:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -text | grep -ie 'subject:\|alternative\dns'
DNS:aws.updates.jenkins.io

However, when I try, with the --servername option, it gives the correct DNS name
echo | openssl s_client -connect updates.jenkins.io:443 -servername updates.jenkins.io 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -text | grep -ie 'subject:\|alternative\dns'
DNS:updates.jenkins.io

Both updates.jenkins.io and aws.updates.jenkins.io have the same IP address. Is there any way we can have the default SSL pointing to updates.jenkins.io instead of aws.updates.jenkins.io.
